# button click doesnot work second time

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have got a problem here which I am trying to solve for last three days. When I run my iphone app it displays this screen [image: Login]

Everything works fine i.e. If I click "*Log in With Email*" button it does work.

When I click "*Login with Facebook*" it displays this screen[image: Menu]

but once I click "*logout*" button it displays this screen 
[image: Login after logout] without title and "Log in with Email" doesn't work.

What can the problem?

**Code behind logout button:**

```
LoginViewController *LoginviewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]                                                 initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:LoginviewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Logout button resides in UITabbarController(created programmatically). This is the screen shot of ViewController to which I am unable to transition for the second time
[image]

Comment: No need to create new instance on logout button. You can take the previous page's instance and dismiss it.

Comment: try [self popViewController animated:YES];

Comment: push it to navigationcontroller rather than presenting as modal view [self.navigationController pushViewController:LoginviewController animated:YES];

Comment: @BhuXan I tried that but didn't work.

Comment: @superGokun tried that as well but didn't work.

Comment: @BHuXan as long as logout button is not in tabBarController, your code works.

Comment: how you are persenting second view by using log in with email btn?

Comment: @Dilip Login_in_With_Email_ViewController *loginEmail = [[Login_in_With_Email_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login_in_With_Email_ViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginEmail animated:YES];

Comment: have you tried to present view instead of pushing it on navigation controller?

Comment: bcoz in your second view you are not displaying navigation bar so, preesent view is better

Comment: @Dilip Yup Its presenting now. But since I am not pushing it so I have no way to go back.

Comment: Just add [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; line in Logout button block.

Comment: Didn't work since the logout button is in TabBarController

Answer (score 1):

What did you assign VC for `UITabBarController` ? I bet `UIViewController`? Try assign `UINavigationController` instead of `UIViewController`

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
SomeViewController *viewController = [[SomeViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];
navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewController];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
viewController, nil]];
```

Then on `SomeViewController.m`

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

in `anotherViewController.m`

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for presenting viewController in login with email btn:

```
 LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
```

And for go back to your login page put this code in logout btn:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: I am not sure whether u r clear about app flow. Let me revise it. Login with Facebook -> Tabcontroller(Which has logout button) and Login with Email -> Some other controller

Comment: when I click logout and return back to Controller(Which has two login buttons) after that I am unable to reach Login with email->Some other controller

Comment: loginviewcontroler is a vc that contain logout,show frnd,app user,etc all this btn, right?

Comment: Nop. LoginViewController has just two Login buttons(as shown in pic). There's another vc contained in TabBarController which has logout,show friends etc buttons.

Comment: then in our code put your tabbar vc name instead of login vc and check that same problem occurred or not..

Comment: The problem is something related to NavigationController. It's unable to push "Login with email" after logout has been clicked

Answer (score 0):

may be check your code for anywhere does you disabled the User Interaction for `Log in with Email` button while presenting your `LoginviaFacebook` controller.

Comment: Yeah checked that. Its working fine for the first time. But when I return back (after clicking logout) and click "Login with Email" button it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, i understood. may be its not releasing your view from top or added it.  Just check by providing background color of your view.

Comment: The problem is something related to NavigationController. It's unable to push "Login with email" after logout has been clicked

Answer (score 0):

So guys I solved the issue. Following code should have been placed in Logout button

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appDelegate.LoginviewController];

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];